# Tomcat 7 behind NGINX forwarding ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx, tomcat7

I have currently setup Apache Tomcat 7 in port 8080 and I am using NGINX with a Let's Encrypt SSL in front of it as a reverse proxy. The current configuration is working like a charm, but I need one be able to pass to Tomcat when the page been view is using SSL or not.

I found on the documentation the use of SSLValve in the server.xml file should do the trick, but the examples I have found are for apache as the reverse proxy and not for NGINX.

Has anyone done this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using :8080 as the backend for both http and https:

```
server {
  listen :80;
  listen :443 defaultserver ssl;
  ...ssl directives....

  location ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://apache:8080;
}
```

NGINX configuration can fill in the ssl directive parts for your particular case
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: I was able to setup that part and it is working like a charm, but when I do this <%=request.isSecure()%> I always see that SSL is false and I am even passing the proxy params back to tomcat